# Refactor static method calls into calls on instance of injected singleton

Tags: java, android, unit-testing, dagger

When I first setup my application I wanted to store some data in the application class. I think I am doing this in a "safe" way, but that is not really the subject of this question.

Here is an example of what I have now.

```
private static String email;  

public static void saveEmailId(String emailToSave) {
    cachedPersistData.saveEmailId(emailToSave);  // save to file
    email = emailToSave;
}

public static String getEmail() {
    return email;
}

public void onCreate() {
    ...
    email = persistData.readEmailId();  // restore from file
    ...
}
```

The idea being if I always used the static methods, I would be setting and getting the value s from the same place. (I did not really understand singletons at the time , and read some blogs that implied that was not a good way to go anyway).

This leaves me with a lot of calls like this in my application.

```
MyApp.saveEmailId("blah");
MyApp.getEmailId();
```

Now that I am learning about testing (using Robolectric and Mockito) I think those static method calls are going to be problematic.
First off,  am I wrong about that?  I saw something called PowerMock which might help with this?

I have started leaning about and using Dagger, so I am considering refactoring these methods in to non-static methods and using an @Singleton annotated Dagger provider to inject an instance of the app object whenever I need to make a call to one of these methods.

Since I think the refactoring might me a big job, would like some help trying to understand the pro's and con's of

1. Leaving the code as is (static variables and methods) and trying to 
   work around the test implications.
2. Refactoring the static methods and calls into calls on a Dagger injected singleton instance.

**UPDATE**

I am beginning to wonder if I can eliminate the static method calls

In order to inject an instance of the application into a class I need the ObjectGraph which is in the application.

so if I have an annotated field like this

```
@Inject Myapp app;
```

In a class constructor or onCreate() method I think I would still need something like

```
public void onCreate() {
    MyApp.inject(this);
}
```

This seems like a chicken and the egg problem.

Comment: For the *why is static bad* part, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7026507/why-are-static-variables-considered-evil Regarding the refactoring, your IDE might help you do the job more easily, read it's documentation (read about: method inlining)